# Looking up lots of individual id's

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a query that is a final step in my program that passes anywhere from 20-50k unique id's. I need to retrieve some of those rows data. The base table has ~15 million rows. Is there a good way to approach this? Currently doing this in Postgres is not adequate performance.

I am open to using a different technology other than a SQL based db. Performance is all that matters.

```
 SELECT my_params FROM table WHERE id in (' + set_of_ids + ')
 ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 100
```

Comment: Where do you get the IDs from?

Comment: ID's come from another database and are post-processed in a Python program.

Comment: How fast do you need this to return?

Comment: Currently I am getting ~2-4seconds in psql, bringing down below 0.5s is the target.

Comment: Does the table have any index(es) on it currently?

Comment: when post processed can you then dump them into a table on the same server you want to query.  make it the primary key then you just have to join the two tables on primary keys? Otherwise a list of 50K ids that are 6 digits is 300,000 characters just transferring that string will be some work for the servers....

Comment: Could also try something like:
select my_params from foo
   inner join (
      select id1 as bar
      union all select id2
      union all select id3
      ...
   ) as x on foo.bar = x.

Comment: @Nicarus: yes, the id's match the tables primary key

Comment: @Matt: I'll give that a try. Everything is happening on the same physical server, so I cant see 300k chars taking that long.

Answer (score 0):

Create a temporary table and `COPY` the values into it in the same transaction.

Sprinkle with indices as needed and join the two tables.

Bon appetit!

Answer (score 0):

The performance of a query with a large IN lists can very often be improved by rewriting it to a JOIN using a `VALUES` clause:

```
SELECT t.my_params 
FROM table t
JOIN (
  VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),.....
) as x(id) on x.id = t.id;
```